# How can the text typed in an EditText survive to the destruction of the Activity?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm starting to learn&use Android Java programming. I learned that when an app is running and the display is rotated the activity is paused, stopped and destroyed and then created and started again.
But, if I filled out an EditText before the rotation, the typed text survives the rotation and it is present in the rotated screen.
How is it possible?

Comment: You need to save the value in saveinstance or you can use ViewModel to persist the data. ViewModel will be recommended way to do it

Comment: Activities and fragments invoke [`View.onSaveInstanceState()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#onSaveInstanceState()) to carry over the state. You can disable this behavior by adding `android:saveEnabled=false` to your edit texts xml or calling `setSaveEnabled` in your code.